# Simple MySQL select query one field and return value

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to return and display the value from one column where the ID matches. So simple but it would help if I knew what I was doing.

```
    <?php 
      if(isset($_GET['cid'])) {
      $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cid']);
      $query = "SELECT C_T_o_R FROM Ctable WHERE C_ID = '{$cid}'";
      $results = mysql_query($query);
      $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
      $CToR = $rows;
      echo $CToR;
     } ?>
```

Comment: You don't need to prefix your questions with how new you are at something. Just state what you are trying to do, explain what you have tried, and what the difference is between what you expected and what happened. In cases like this, `print_r($rows)` is very helpful to see what type the variable is (array) and what is in it (keys and values).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. `mysql_fetch_assoc()` fetches an array from your results. You just need to specify the column (key) from that array:

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_GET['cid'])) {
  $cid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cid']);
  $query = "SELECT C_T_o_R FROM Ctable WHERE C_ID = '{$cid}'";
  $results = mysql_query($query);
  $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
  $CToR = $rows['C_T_o_R']; // <-- THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED TO DO 
  echo $CToR;
 } ?>
```

Comment: Also `$cid` appears to be undefined.

Comment: Good catch. Let me fix that here.

Comment: Knew it was something simple!  That worked great! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array and you cannot echo an array,
so use `print_r` or `var_dump` to view the result.